# Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\xA4\x96<b...' for column 'body' at row 1

Tags: mysql, jdbc, character-set, unicode, utf-8

I've set the column type to utf8mb4 and the collation to utf8mb4_bin.
The table defaults are also utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_bin.

When I use SequelPro to add the emoji "" to the database manually, it works just fine.

However, when I do an INSERT using JDBC, it gives me the Incorrect String Value error.

Here is my connection string:  `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myschema`
I'm using `mysql-connector-java-5.1.32-bin.jar`

What am I doing wrong?

Here is some of the code I'm using:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (?)"
String body = ...;
statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
statement.setString(1, body)
statement.execute();
```

Comment: One thing you're doing wrong is not posting your code. Another one is you post your question on the wrong site.

Comment: added some code.

Comment: You also need to connect with utf8mb4:  `?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8`

Answer (score 1):

You probably should upgrade your MySQL Java connector to a later version, best to the one matching your MySQL server. [utf8mb4 support was added in version 5.5.3.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874795/mysql-utf8-encoding-issue-incorrect-string-value/13874937#13874937)